# 'DF_PROJECT_ID' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: dialogflow-es

Following simple procedures from https://github.com/dialogflow/agent-human-handoff-nodejs

`DF_PROJECT_ID=<project ID> DF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH=<path to key file> node app.js`

returns

`'DF_PROJECT_ID' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Am I missing any installation?

Comment: hotfix: edited the node.js to include the `DF_PROJECT_ID` and `DF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH` manually.

Comment: You can also check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv for managing environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It should not happen unless you have something running on port :3000. Simple npm install while in that folder should install all dependencies.

BTW, If you are running only one agent, You can edit and update app.js file so instead of using env.params you might have them in app.js :

So back to replacement part  go in app.js and  replace:

> //const projectId = process.env.DF_PROJECT_ID; replace this line
>
> const projectId = "yourprojectId-12345"; //with this line using your id

same for keyPath :

> //const keyPath = process.env.DF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH;
>
> const keyPath = "prc92a8299201fe19965e64389fb28eea5c36b2ef";

so you can run app by typing

> node app.js

or :

> forever start app.js

in case you have forever installed.